# How to exhaust a generator without using "list()"?

Tags: python

Having a generator is there a way to exhaust the generator without using `list()`?

This code sample will not print anything:

```py
(print(i) for i in range(10))
```

It will only do so. If I "invoke" it with `list`

```py
list((print(i) for i in range(10)))
```

This is the usual practice I know and which is at least to my knowledge a vastly used technique.

If executed in the REPL, the number `0-9` are printed as expected and I receive a `list` of 10 `None`.
This makes perfect sense, as `print` doesn't return anything. However the program needs to store all these `None`s in a `list` only to throw them away just afterwards.

This is very wasteful and subverts the generator's intention not to create large memory peaks.

I can implement my own utility function, which doesn't have this issue:

```py
def do(iterable):
    for _ in iterable:
        pass

do((print(i) for i in range(10)))
```

Is there a similar functionality in the stdlib, or do I need to use my own utility function?

I admit, this only makes sense, if a generator has side effects and I am not interested in the generated values like in this simple example.

Comment: Using a generator for side effects already "subverts the intention" of generators.

Comment: Indeed, the road to unintended consequences is paved with subverted intentions.

Comment: `deque(generator)`